# Encapsulate a simple type using C++ templates

Tags: c++, templates, types, operator-overloading

I'm looking to add functionality to all the simple types in C++.

I want to write a single templated class that takes as a template parameter the type to be encapsulated and then has all the operators defined so that the encapsulated class works exactly as the simple type it encapsulates.

Something like this:

```
template <typename _SimpleType_>
class Attribute
{
public:
    Attribute(_SimpleType_ value){ m_value = value; }
    ~Attribute(){}

    // Cast
    operator _SimpleType_() { return(m_value); }

    // Comparisons
    bool operator==(const a& other) const { return a == m_value; }
    etc...

private:
   _SimpleType_ m_value;
}

// Use like:
Attribute<int> i = 20;

while(i)
{
   if((i & 0xF) == 0)
   {
      i >>= 2;
   }

   i--;
}  etc...
```

The question is I'm sure there are a load of nuances that have to be dealt with and specialised template operators written; so is there anywhere that this has already been done so that I can just use that instead?

Boost is too large and complicated to put in my project but I can look at it for pointers if there is a class like this in there - whats its name if there is?

Comment: Note that you can use only the parts of boost that you actually need.  If you only need shared_ptr, only add shared_ptr.hpp to your project.  Many of the libraries are header files only, so you don't need to add anything to your build process.

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty simple, if tedious, - you just have to implement all the operators supported by the standard types and where the cast operator is not sufficient.

I have to ask though, why on earth are you trying to do this?

Comment: One good reason would be to make the default constructor properly construct the contained type. So no more uninitialized variables.

Comment: Not good enough. Compilers warn about uninitialized variables anyway.

Comment: Maybe YOUR compiler warns about uninitialized variables. Not every compiler is necessarily setup to do so.

Comment: My reason is to make a strong typedef / named typedef of an entity that should act as an integer.

Comment: @CygnusX1 so why don't you just use `typedef` or `using`?

Comment: @ancientchild Because that's not a strong typedef. A strong typedef is a separate type, it does not give implicit conversion to/from what was typedefed. Regular typedef or using gives merely a different name, but it is not a distinct type.

Comment: @CygnusX1 got it. Having or not having implicit conversions is indeed a difference!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of doing with an automatic typecast to T& (tested with GNU C++ 4.3.2):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Attribute {
public:
    Attribute(const T &value) { v = value; }
    operator T & () { return v; }
private:
    T v;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Attribute<int> i(0);
    i = 3;
    i++;
    i += 4;
    i = i + 5;
    i <<= 3;
    cout << "i is now " << i << endl;
}
```

The C++ compiler casts automagically the reference to 'Attribute' to a reference to 'int' using the coercion operator 'operator T & ()'. So when the Attribute class does not provide the '++' operator or anything, the object is typecasted to int & and then the operator is looked up from there. Feel free to experiment.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the implementation of the nonmutating operators for free, just by the conversion to `_Simple_type_` (and you would get the assignments and increment/decrement by conversion to `_Simple_type_&`). Another question is whether this is really a good idea, as it creates conversions both `T` to `Attribute<T>` and `Attribute<T>` to `T` which causes problems while overloading - but you could fix that by making the constructor of `Attribute<T>` explicit.

This leaves the assignments and increment/decrement - you would just have to implement those.

Another possibility is using `boost::operators` - a header only library that facilitates creation of operator overloads based on algebraic rules. eg. you create `operator+=`, and it will provide you `operator+`. You create `operator<` and `operator==` and it will give you the other relationals etc.

Answer (score 1):

Not to do with your question, but you should be aware that names such as `_SimpleType_` (that is, names that begin with an underscore and an uppercase character) are reserved for the C++ compiler and Standard Libarary implementors to use - you are not allowed to use them in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `boost::ref` is what you're looking for.

At any rate, the best thing you'd do is to just write it out by hand -- but this will start becoming a problem if you intend to support pointer and reference semantics.

What you'd also proabably need to do is put it in a namespace and implement the free function operator overloads and rely on ADL for it to get picked up. This will get a little unwieldy though as you implement more and more operators.

Answer (score 0):

I like this form of encapsulation of simple types (*original author - Sektor van Skijlen*):

```
template<typename T>
class explicit_t
{
private:
    T value;

    template<typename V> explicit_t(V t);
public:
    operator T&() {return value;}
    explicit_t(const T& c) : value(c) {}    
};
```

And the short example:

```
void fun(explicit_t<int> foo) {}

int main()
{
        // fun('a');
        // fun(3u);
        // fun(3.0);
        fun(4);
}
```

So what do I get? No more unwanted conversions.

You might also want to have a look at something more fancy - [typegen](http://msobczak.com/prog/typegen/).